# How can I getIntent from ViewHolder in RecyclerView ?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to get data from another Activity and set my text to those data in my onBindViewHolder, how can I do that, any ideas ?

Comment: maybe convert your context, that you send to your adapter, to an activity and then get your intent. so `adapter(Activity context); context.getIntent();`

Comment: when I ve tried to implement your I ve got an error in new ViewHolder(view) : View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_path,null);
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view); But the good think is may be your solution it seems to work, but I ve to fixe this new problem

Comment: what error do you get? can you post your code and the log

Comment: Error:(54, 61) error: incompatible types: Context cannot be converted to Activity

Comment: Finally!!! Thanks for all your help ;)

Comment: oke. can you post the code where you create the adapter.

Comment: does it work now? if it does i will write the answer and you can accept that

Comment: Yes! I have just to add try and catch Exception to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the adapter, send your Activity as context.

Then

```
adapter(Activity context); 
..
context.getIntent();
..
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful code of RecyclerView. Might it will help others. It is complete working example.

http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/